# JavaScript regexp select only last occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

#### Select only last occurrence

I'm trying to select last word (until space), those are come after last `white space` and `@` character.

Following is my string

```
hello hi @why helo @blow but @name             // capture: name
hello hi @why helo @blow but name@name         // capture: blow
```

and another string

```
@blow but not know how to resolve this         // capture: blow
```

Here last occurrence is a first word `blow`, select only `@` after word (obviously whitespace is not in first word).

I tryed this: https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/1

Comment: Is selecting with *capture groups* an option?

Comment: No, I am selecting string when cursor, click on the paragraph that paragraph left all string will be select and find last space and @ after string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer:

```
/\B@[^@]\w*(?!.*?\s@)/
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/5)

Comment: second line I need to capture `blow` not the `name`.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: shouldn't you use word boundaries in the lookahead?

Comment: @CommuSoft Not required in lookahead.. `\s` is  more precise here.. can you think of why? :P

Comment: Yes because it cannot be the start of the string anymore. But `\B` is not equivalent to `(^|\s|$)`, it for instance matches `$` as well.

Comment: @CommuSoft hmmm exactly... i was interested in something like `hey @blow this name-@name`

Comment: @karthikmanchala: well if you want to be absolutely sure you pick the last one, you better use a pattern with `R(?!.*R)` with `R` the part in which you are interested. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use negative lookahead:

```
@[^@]\w*(?!.*@[^@]\w*)
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kY4wL1/1).

`(?:)` means that the regex inside it cannot occur after that point. So this regex states that after the matched item, you cannot find another @-thing next to it. That means it is the last `@`-thing evidently.

Note that for the case:

```
@blow but not know how to resolve this@
^                                     ^
|                                     |
will match this one                   |
        because this is not a valid @/
```

the `@blow` is selected, because the `@` - according to your regex needs at least one character. If you want to match the `@` part, you need to modify this to:

```
@[^@]?\w*(?!.*@[^@]?\w*)
```

or more efficient

```
@[^@]?\w*(?!.*@)
```

If the `@` must be preceeded by the begin of the string, or whitespace, you can use a word boundary `\B`:

```
\B@[^@]?\w*(?!.*\B@[^@]?\w*)
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uD8wY5/2)

Comment: second line I need to capture `blow` not the `name`.

Comment: Sorry, but not worked well, not select all three line that I need, thank you for helping.

Comment: @S͢kyD͢ream: forgot the `gmi`flags, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:^|\s)(@[^@]\w*)(?!.*\s@)/
```

should work; your word will be the 1st capture. In a language that supports lookbehinds, you could do

```
/(?<=^|\s)@[^@]\w*(?!.*\s@)/
```

and have the whole capture be what you seek; however that is not possible in JavaScript.

If you are satisfied with a mere word break and not necessarily a space, this works as well:

```
/\b@[^@]\w*(?!.*\s@)/
```

The idea is to check with positive lookahead that no further `@word` is after our match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^| )@([^@\s]+)(?!.*?\s@\w+.*$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/3

Comment: `whitespace` and `@` do not capture. I need only word those are after the `whitespace` and `@` at last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, how about something like this?

```js
var strings = [
    'hello hi @why helo @blow but @name',
    'hello hi @why helo @blow but name@name',
    '  hello   hi   @why   helo    @blow    but    name@name  ',
    '@blow but not know how to resolve this',
    '  @blow   but   not   know   how   to   resolve   this',
    'tada',
    '    ',
    ''
];

var wanted = strings.map(function (element) {
    var found = 'not found';
    
    element.split(/\s+/).reverse().some(function (part) {
        if (part.charAt(0) === '@') {
            found = part.slice(1);
            
            return true;
        }
    });
    
    return found;
});

document.getElementById('out').textContent = wanted.join('\n')
```

```html
<pre id='out'></pre>
```

No complex RegExp, easy to understand and change behaviour. does require ES5 or shims but no biggy.

Comment: Yeah, right, but I wanna make dropdown to display username base on @ after typed word.

Comment: That's not a problem with this method either.